# MySQL user wildcard use BETWEEN

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a problem in MySQL Query, this is my Query:

```
select `BKC ID`,`Nama Pengirim`,sum(`&#162; Koli`) as `Koli`,sum(`Harga`) as `Harga Barang`, sum(`Uang Administrasi`) as `Admin.`, sum(`Uang Penerus`) as `Uang Penerus`, `Tujuan`
from `transaksi` 
join `transaksi barang` 
ON `transaksi barang`.`BARANG ID` LIKE concat(`transaksi`.`BKC ID`, '-%')
WHERE `BKC ID` BETWEEN ('%1705%' AND '%1706%')
group by `BKC ID` DESC
```

but that query is ERROR, the error is **can't to use WILDCARD at BETWEEN function**,

i can't to find alternatif @ google.com (Seaching) 
Type of `BKC ID` is **varchar**, example **"ABC170101102912"**

**thanks for advance.**

Comment: no,is different, i has been find it, but this not same, i have type is "varchar" not interget , decimal , or all same about numeric. @Alvin

Comment: What is alternatif to change my Query @saveen?

Comment: No you cannot use a wildcard in a between statement. Since a wildcard could mean anything i.e. infinity it would never return. Remember the % indicates any number of characters thus where do I start or stop?

Comment: "the error is can't to use WILDCARD at BETWEEN function" No, it isn't. There is no such error message.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those numbers you want to check with the between seem to be a year and a month.

So for the years 2010 to 2019 that number will always start with a 1

Hence you could locate the position of the first 1, then take the next 4 characters with a substring.

Then compare that substring with the date range.

```
...
WHERE cast(substring(`BKC ID`, locate('1',`BKC ID`), 4) as unsigned) between 1701 and 1706
...
```

That's assuming that the first letter part of the string doesn't have a fixed length.
Because if you know it's always 3 characters, then it can be simplified:

```
...
WHERE cast(substring(`BKC ID`,4,4) as unsigned) between 1701 and 1706
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value you want to test starts at the first numeric position in the string you could do something like this

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select 'ABC170101102912',
    ->  cast(
    -> SUBSTR('ABC170101102912',LEAST (
    ->     if (Locate('0','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('0','ABC170101102912'),999),
    ->     if (Locate('1','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('1','ABC170101102912'),999),
    ->     if (Locate('2','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('2','ABC170101102912'),999),
    ->     if (Locate('3','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('3','ABC170101102912'),999),
    ->     if (Locate('4','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('4','ABC170101102912'),999),
    ->     if (Locate('5','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('5','ABC170101102912'),999),
    ->     if (Locate('6','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('6','ABC170101102912'),999),
    ->     if (Locate('7','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('7','ABC170101102912'),999),
    ->     if (Locate('8','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('8','ABC170101102912'),999),
    ->     if (Locate('9','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('9','ABC170101102912'),999)
    ->   , length('ABC170101102912') ),4)
    ->   as int)   as NewString,
    ->
    ->    case when  cast(
    -> SUBSTR('ABC170101102912',LEAST (
    ->     if (Locate('0','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('0','ABC170101102912'),999),
    ->     if (Locate('1','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('1','ABC170101102912'),999),
    ->     if (Locate('2','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('2','ABC170101102912'),999),
    ->     if (Locate('3','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('3','ABC170101102912'),999),
    ->     if (Locate('4','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('4','ABC170101102912'),999),
    ->     if (Locate('5','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('5','ABC170101102912'),999),
    ->     if (Locate('6','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('6','ABC170101102912'),999),
    ->     if (Locate('7','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('7','ABC170101102912'),999),
    ->     if (Locate('8','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('8','ABC170101102912'),999),
    ->     if (Locate('9','ABC170101102912') >0,Locate('9','ABC170101102912'),999)
    ->   , length('ABC170101102912') ),4)
    ->   as int) between 1701 and 1706 then 'Between'
    ->   else 'not between'
    ->   end as isit;
+-----------------+-----------+---------+
| ABC170101102912 | NewString | isit    |
+-----------------+-----------+---------+
| ABC170101102912 |      1701 | Between |
+-----------------+-----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```